# Não consigo iniciar um serviço

Tags: android, android-service

Estou tentando substituir um código que eu fiz utilizando thead por services ,mas quando eu crio o service ele não inicia (não inicia nenhum método do service) e pesquisando na net ví algumas soluções que falavam que poderia ser no "manifest.xml" mas as alterações que eu fiz não resolveram o problema.

A minha dúvida é : Aonde eu estou errando?

O manifesto:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"

    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Metronome.Theme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Metronome.Main.Theme" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <service android:name=".Compasso"/>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.ConfiguracoesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_configuracoes"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Este é o método na activity que eu tento iniciar o service:

```
public void executar(){
        FrontConversor conversor = new FrontConversor();

        conversor.setVibracao(true);
        conversor.setFlash(false);

        conversor.setTempoMinutos(npTimer.getValue());
        conversor.setFrequenciaBPM(npBPM.getValue());
        conversor.setQuantidadeBatidas(npQntBatidas.getValue());

        conversor.createSomById(getIdSom(), this);
        conversor.createFiguraRitmicaById(npValorBase.getValue());

        //executer.preExecuter(conversor, this); // preparar

        startService(new Intent(this,Compasso.class)); // executar
}
```

E esta é uma parte da classe que extend service (classe compasso):

```
public class Compasso extends Service{
...

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("MARK","Service iniciado");

        double frequenciaSegundos = this.conversorBPM(this.frequenciaBPM); // 2bps
        double Delay = 1000 / frequenciaSegundos; // 0.5s

        int tempoMiliSegundos = (this.tempoMinutos * 60 * 1000); // (60000 milisegundos)
        double quantidadeCiclo = tempoMiliSegundos / (this.batidasMaximo * Delay);

        this.stopNow = false;

        try {

            // Iniciando ciclo de batidas
            loopSound(Delay, quantidadeCiclo);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            this.stopMetronomo();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

...

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
    }

}
```

Pelo que eu acho que deverá retornar quando o service iniciar será um erro (nullpointerException) mas nem mesmo erro ele retorna.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: No manifest, `<service>` não é no mesmo nível de `<activity>` (não dentro dela)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedro, no AndroidManifest você declarou o serviço dentro da Tag `<activity>`. E correto é que dentro Tag `<application>`. Veja o Exemplo:

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".Compasso" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Referência: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Declaring

Answer (score 0):

Vlw , povo.
Achei aonde eu estava errando no manifest ,além da declaração de service está fora de activity eu esqueci que estou separando as classes segundo o MVC e a classe compasso está dentro do pacote control.

Logo ficou assim (resumidamente) o maifest:

```
<manifest ... >
...
  <application ... >
  <service android:name=".control.Compasso" />
  ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```